# How to configure the cpaenl

Tags: php, cpanel

am using Cpanel shared hosting and am using php 4.0 version so how to change the version and also how to add the below the extension in our php.ini.

"extension=php_com_dotnet.dll"

is there possible when using the shared hosting?

Comment: all depends on your hosting provider and the package/plan you selected

Comment: `php 4.0` Are you serious ?

Comment: that php 4. something..

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** do that on your own as you are on Shared Hosting. Submit a ticket to your hosting provider to tell them to update the PHP version. (I am sure they won't since it will affect other users on their rack). So it is better to change your hosting provider. Because the latest PHP version is **`5.5.7`** and you still want to be in **`4.X.X`** ? Just think.

Comment: ok thanks.... how to add that extension? our provider also dont know about that...so only

Comment: First of all that dll `php_com_dotnet.dll` needs to be added inside the `ext` folder of the PHP installation directory. After that, add the line `extension=php_com_dotnet.dll` on your PHP.ini and do a restart.